# JQuery to Remove a Selected Option in A DropDown from other DropDowns , stops working and hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, freeze

I am using the following javascript to remove a option selected in DropDown A , from DropDown B.

```
$('#A').bind('keypress', function(e){ 

      if ( e.which == 52 ){
        var selectedItems  = $('#A').val();
        var $list = $("#B"),
            toRemove = $(),
            selectedItems = $("#A").val();
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
          toRemove = toRemove.add($list.find('option[value="' + selectedItems[i] + '"]'));
        }
        toRemove.remove();
      }
});
```

The option is removed from DropDown B  , but , the javascript hangs out when I press the key. Please help.

Is there some other jquery ?

Comment: What does "hangs out" mean? Do you get an error message in the JavaScript console?

Comment: All other javascripts on the page, stuck up , like i have a tooltip on the column in which dropdown A exists, and that tooltip remains open

Comment: But the item _is_ actually removed from dropdown B? There are several things I'd change in your code, but none of them explain other controls or functions getting broken.

Comment: @nnnnnn : sir, is there some other javascript which I could use? this one's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why everything is hanging, but I think there are some things that could be improved in your code.

If you have a "dropdown" then the select element will be single-select, which means the [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will be returning a string rather than an array (it only returns an array in the case of a `<select multiple="multiple">` element), and if it's returning a string you don't need the for loop because - well, there's nothing to loop through. If that is true the simplified version of your code would be this:

```
$('#A').bind('keypress', function(e){
    if ( e.which === 52 ){
       $('#B option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```

If there is no matching option in #B for the selected item then nothing will happen.

I don't understand the significance of key code 52, but I've left that in.

Comment: sir, the select A is multiple